# Unable to connect to broadband in Windows 8 via Ethernet

Tags: windows-8, internet-connection, broadband

I tried connecting my laptop (Windows 8.0) to broadband. The first attempt was successful. Later I restarted my laptop and tried again and all successive attempts have failed. A weird behavior I observed is even if my Ethernet cable is plugged out, it still shows my broadband to be connected as in this screenshot.

[image: Image is here]

I tried to ping www.google.com and ,as expected, the host was reported to be unreachable.
Please let me know if any other details are required.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the blow steps and check the results,

> Navigate to Device Manager - Network Adaptors - right click your network adapter - Click Properties and then, under Device status, check to see that the device is working properly.
>
> On your network Adapter  - Disable it and enable it again
>
> Power off the modem and power it on after few minutes.
>
> If possible try a different LAN cable and check the status
>
> Run the automated troubleshooter, it is a  windows tool that can find and automatically fix some problems with your computer. To start this, Right-click the Picture of the wired network icon in the notification area of your taskbar, and then click Troubleshoot problems.

Comment: I tried the suggested procedure but it didn't work. The adaptor refused to get deleted/disconnected/disabled. The troubleshooter found the problem to be DNS not reachable. Meanwhile, I have created another broadband connection and it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

It happens like that sometimes. It was not disconnected properly. So

```
Right click the BSNL Adapater & click disable 
Now the adapter will be disabled
Then Again Right Clik on the Adapter & click enable
It will enable the BSNL adapter
```

Comment: Can you expand on this? As it stands, it's too low-quality to justify a full answer.